# Security context in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Under the K8s component Statefulset as shown below, the security context works fine for Kubernetes 1.21 version, but when I tried with new versions it did not work fine. I understand this is due to the fact that there is 'PodSecurityPolicy deprecation' in the latest versions. But I am unable to find an alternative on how to use ' securityContext: fsGroup: 1001 ' in the yaml file. Appreciate any guidance on this ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zfYw.png)

Comment: Was the answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation from the [Kubernetes official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/), is migrating to [Pod Security Admission](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-admission/).

Unfortunately, the migration is not as easy as just changing a particular line on a manifest, it will take a very detailed process since it could lead to a production outage or to a security gap.

In the [Migrate from PSP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/migrate-from-psp/) documentation, you can find an overall approach to accomplish a successful migration:

> There are multiple strategies you can take for migrating from
> PodSecurityPolicy to Pod Security Admission. The following steps are
> one possible migration path, with a goal of minimizing both the risks
> of a production outage and of a security gap.
>
> 0. Decide whether Pod Security Admission is the right fit for your use case.
> 1. Review namespace permissions
> 2. Simplify & standardize PodSecurityPolicies
> 3. Update namespaces
>
>    1. Identify an appropriate Pod Security level
>    2. Verify the Pod Security level
>    3. Enforce the Pod Security level
>    4. Bypass PodSecurityPolicy
> 4. Review namespace creation processes
> 5. Disable PodSecurityPolicy